# Typo3 Depedency Injection on BackendModule is not working

Tags: php, typo3

I am trying to create a backend module based on `Extbase` like described here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/HowTo/BackendModule/CreateModuleWithExtbase.html

I get the following error:

```
Too few arguments to function Peni4142\ImageCompressor\Controller\ImageCompressorController::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 2961 and exactly 1 expected
```

It seems the dependency injection is not working but I have no idea.

Do you have any hints?

Stacktrace:

```
in /var/www/html/ext/image_compressor/Classes/Controller/ImageCompressorController.php line 14

at Peni4142\ImageCompressor\Controller\ImageCompressorController->__construct()
in /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php line 2961

at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('Peni4142\\ImageCompressor\\Controller\\ImageCompressorController')
in /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Http/Dispatcher.php line 86
```

The Controller

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Peni4142\ImageCompressor\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Attribute\Controller;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Template\ModuleTemplateFactory;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;

#[Controller]
final class ImageCompressorController extends ActionController
    {
     public function __construct(
         protected readonly ModuleTemplateFactory $moduleTemplateFactory,
     ) {

     }

     // use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     public function handleRequest(): ResponseInterface
     {
         $this->view->assign('someVar', 'someContent');
         $moduleTemplate = $this->moduleTemplateFactory->create($this->request);
         // Adding title, menus, buttons, etc. using $moduleTemplate ...
         $moduleTemplate->setContent($this->view->render());
         return $this->htmlResponse($moduleTemplate->renderContent());
     }
}
```

Configuration/Backend/Modules.php

```
<?php

use Peni4142\ImageCompressor\Controller\ImageCompressorController;

return [
    'image_compressor_config' => [
        'parent' => 'file',
        'position' => ['after' => '*'],
        'access' => 'admin',
        // 'path' => '/module/system/permissions',
        'extensionName' => 'Image Compressor',
        'iconIdentifier' => 'module-permission',
        'navigationComponent' => '@typo3/backend/page-tree/page-tree-element',
        'labels' => [
            'title' => 'Image Compressor',
            'description' => 'Compressing images',
            'shortDescription' => 'Creating compressed images and stores compressing Template'
        ],
        'aliases' => ['system_BeuserTxPermission'],
        'routes' => [
            '_default' => [
                'target' => ImageCompressorController::class . '::handleRequest',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

partial composer.json

```
  "require": {
    "typo3/cms-core": "^12",
    "typo3/cms-backend": "^12",
    "typo3/cms-extbase": "^12",
    "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^12",
    "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^12"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Peni4142\\ImageCompressor\\": "Classes/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "typo3-ter/personal": "self.version"
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "extension-key": "image_compressor"
    }
  }
```

Because I am new to PHP, I have to say I used the text editor to create the composer file; I didn't use any commands to add them to the composer file.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look into `in /var/www/html/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Http/Dispatcher.php` at line 86 of your backtrace. As you can see TYPO3 will try to instanciate your class with Symfony DI/Container first before it will try the `GeneralUtility::makeInstance` way.

So, as Symfony DI can not find your Controller in Symfony container I'm pretty sure that your controller is in section `getRemovedIds` of `var/cache/code/di/DependencyInjection_[hash].php` file.

As you have marked your controller with attribute `#Controller` already and the extending `ActionController` looks correct, it seems, that you have forgotten to Flush Cache in InstallTool of TYPO3. That button needs a few seconds, as it also re-creates the DependencyInjection file in cache. After flushing cache your controller should be in section `methodMap` and should work like expected.

Stefan

Comment: For some reason, the maintenance module is showing a blank page… Some other admin modules as well. I hoped it would have been solved together. Maybe I have to read the logs or remove my extension shortly. I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Ok I could manage to try this already and it seems I could open a new thread to solve that problem first :D

Comment: Alternative you can just delete the DependencyInjection file from var directory. It will automatically re-created with next website request. Further solution is visiting InstallTool directly over typo3/install.php and flush cache over there.